# Shapefiles with Ireland's Inland Waterways

Tags: shapefile, matplotlib, waterways, lakes, ireland

I wish to produce a set of polygons for each county on the island of Ireland. I found shapefiles here of all 32 counties:

https://www.townlands.ie/page/download/

The problem is that there are no lakes and the Shannon Estuary is missing. I wish to include the lakes as holes in the case where a county encompasses a lake.

**UPDATE**

I found shapefiles for lakes here:

```
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-lakes/
```

but I still have a number of problems: a) The lake resolution is too low with respect to the county data b) There is no Shannon Estuary. What might I do to produce the 32 polygons I require?

[image]

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon, mapping, shape
import fiona
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch

ireland = Polygon([(-5.34,55.43), (-10.56,55.43), (-10.56,51.39), (-5.34,51.39)])

lakes = []
with fiona.open("./ne_10m_lakes/ne_10m_lakes.shp") as shapes: 
  for s in shapes: lakes.append(shape(s['geometry']))
with fiona.open("./ne_10m_lakes_europe/ne_10m_lakes_europe.shp") as shapes:
  for s in shapes: lakes.append(shape(s['geometry']))
lakes = MultiPolygon([s for s in lakes if s.intersects(ireland)])

counties = {}
with fiona.open("./counties/counties.shp") as shapes:
  for s in shapes:
    assert s['properties']['NAME_EN'][:7] == "County "
    counties[ s['properties']['NAME_EN'][7:] ] = shape(s['geometry'])

counties = [c.difference(lakes) for c in counties.values()]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for s in counties:
    p = PolygonPatch(s)
    ax.add_patch(p)

ax.set_xlim(-11,-5)
ax.set_ylim(50,57)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you are seeking open (often just any) spatial data then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: If you're using Matplotlib, you might like to try the [`drawlsmask`](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawlsmask) option, which can render lakes.

Comment: @Richard Law: I think I just wish to update each county Polygon by adjusting its exterior path or by adding holes in the case of lakes belonging to only one county.

Comment: @Richard Law Updated my question.

Comment: @Baz I think you need to decide whether you just want to find data (use Open Data to ask a new question), or to just draw the lakes without your own source of lake data (I think you should use `drawlsmask` for that).

Answer (score 1):

With matplotlib (Basemap), you can use `drawlsmask` to render lakes.

https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawlsmask

Comment: I've had problems with this since I'm using Python3: https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/356